# Display all IN operator value, with status of 'available' or 'not available'

Tags: sql, sql-server, in-operator

I have list of string like `('222','333','43242','3242')` which I have to used in a table `dummy`, let say my table dummy has only two values from this list `('222','333')`, the data should be show as

```
dummyID    dummyStatus
222        Available
333        Available 
43242      Not Available
3242       Not Available
```

I have tried all possible query like

```
select dummyId, case when dummyId is null 'Available' else 'Not Available' end
from dummy
where dummyId in ('222','333','43242','3242')
```

but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=dd4ddbb75de0ef39a3db045dd257b86e)

1. You `Case When ... Then End` syntax is incorrect
2. You should use *Desired table values* like below

```
select v1.value, 
    case when dummyId is not null then 'Available' else 'Not Available' end as dummyStatus
from (
     values('222'),('333'),('43242'),('3242')
)v1(value)

left join (
     values('222'),('333') -- Let's say your table here
)dummy(dummyId) on v1.value = dummy.dummyId
```

**Updated (Param is '(222,333,43242,3242)')**

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3b9daccc246d0b11b31f33d8f8a4492b)

Let's say we have a `strSplit` function to help us split from string to table, then you can achieve in this way

```
declare @str varchar(200) = '(222,333,43242,3242)'

set @str = REPLACE(REPLACE(@str,'(', ''), ')', '')


select v1.val, 
case when dummyId is not null then 'Available' else 'Not Available' end as dummyStatus
from strSplit(@str, ',')v1

left join (
     values('222'),('333') -- Let's say your table here
)dummy(dummyId) on v1.val = dummy.dummyId
```

**Note**: SQL Server 2016 and later have [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) Then You just do like this, [demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ad358c1bd4c499cc89b9d442f2df04be)

```
declare @str varchar(200) = '(222,333,43242,3242)'

set @str = REPLACE(REPLACE(@str,'(', ''), ')', '')

select v1.value, 
case when dummyId is not null then 'Available' else 'Not Available' end as dummyStatus
from STRING_SPLIT(@str, ',')v1

left join (
     values('222'),('333') -- Let's say your table here
)dummy(dummyId) on v1.value = dummy.dummyId
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: a person always add dummyIds like this format `('222','333','43242','3242')` not in this format `('222'),('333'),('43242'),('3242')
)v1(value)`, I also know this trick which you have given.

Comment: You mean `'222','333','43242','3242'` is a string speratated by comma?

Comment: No, I mean `In operator` in where clause, with value

Comment: You mean include `parentheses` like `('222','333','43242','3242')` , right?

Comment: Yes, include parenthesis and with in operator

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207817/discussion-between-phong-and-faraz-ahmed).

Comment: I've just updated my answer, please take a look at @Faraz Ahmed